# Adding a "where" clause to Rails "include" in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

- Users have many Sites
- Sites have many Controllers
- Controllers have many Inspections

This is what I have at the moment.

```
current_user
   .sites
   .joins(:controllers)
   .where('controllers.inspections_enabled = true')
   .all(:include => [:controllers => [:inspections]])
```

This gives me:

"All sites where a controller is enabled, with all controllers and inspections"

I want

"All sites where a controller is enabled, and include ONLY controllers which has 'inspections_enabled = true', with all it's child inspections"

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why are you including `controllers` in eager load. It is already loaded in memory because of your join. I think your should be `current_user
   .sites
   .joins(:controllers)
   .where('controllers.inspections_enabled = true')
   .all(:include => [:inspections])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should define an association which has defined conditions, see the [*docs*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

> If you do want eager load only some members of an association it is
>   usually more natural to include an association which has conditions
>   defined on it.

in your case:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :inspections_enabled_controllers, 
           :class_name => 'Controller', 
           :conditions => ['inspections_enabled = ?', true]
end

current_user
    .sites
    .joins(:inspections_enabled_controllers)
    .all(:include => [:inspections])
```